# PopOverController parsing value or array in UIPopupViewController class

Tags: ios, ipad

I have one calendar and some events in calendar. 
When user click on event date then open popup, I know how to show popup, but problem is how to parsing table data in my popup class xib ?

Here is my code I get a `null` value.
Here is code for click on event then show popup.
Here I pass a array in popupController `movies.listOfEvent=listOfEvent;`  `movies.listofEvent` this is declared in calendarpopupviewController.

```
NSMutableArray *listOfEvent=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<getEventData.count; i++)
{
    [listOfEvent addObject:[getEventData objectAtIndex:i]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",listOfEvent);
if (self.popoverController == nil)
{
    CalendarPopupViewController *movies = [[CalendarPopupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalendarPopupViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:movies];
    movies.getValue=@"nishant------------";
    movies.listOfEvent=listOfEvent;
    popover.delegate = self;

    self.popoverController = popover;

}

 CGRect popoverRect = getPoint;
 popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100);

[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
                                        inView:self.view
                      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
```

Where do I mistake, how to pass value ? please help me

In my popupviewController code

```
@interface CalendarPopupViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *listOfEvent;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *getValue;
```

and .m file 
    @synthesize listOfEvent;
    @synthesize getValue;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@",getValue);
    NSLog(@"%@",listOfEvent);
}
```

Comment: The problem might with this `self.popoverController == nil`,  If already popOver then the block doesn't get called.

Comment: i was remove this line but problem is not solve